# Combo box control for complex data type in ASP.NET MVC project with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

In ASP.NET MVC 3 project with EF, I'm trying to figure out how to handle a complex data type.

I have an entity Student with property school. When the user create or edit entity Student I want the user to be able to choose the school from list of schools in the DB.

I have the following models:

```
public class TesterDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}    

[DataContract]
public class School
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public School School { get; set; }
}
```

Create method's in the student controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(student);
    }
```

Student create view:

```
@model Tester.Models.Student
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"   type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Student</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Any idea how to add to the create view of the Studnet model a combo box that will let me choose a school from the list of schools in my DB

Thanks!

Comment: How do i add a dropdown box to the view that will be bind to the list of schools in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

In your (get) create method you need to add a method to provide the Schools data:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.SchoolId = new SelectList(db.Schools, "SchoolId", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

then in your view you need to render this data:

```
<fieldset> 
...
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SchoolId, "School")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("SchoolId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SchoolId)
    </div>
...
</fieldset>
```

so that in your post you can retrieve the school ID and apply it to the student object:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
    ViewBag.SchoolId = new SelectList(db.Schools, "SchoolId", "Name", student.SchoolId);
    return View(student);
}
```

Comment: In this solution I need to have a property SchoolId in the student model. Is there any way to do it without having a SchoolId property? and use just the School property?